# how to find a key and set the values to a variable in php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array (print_r output) -

```
Array ( [Ds_Date] => 08%2F06%2F2018 [Ds_Hour] => 12%3A46 [Ds_SecurePayment] => 1 [Ds_Amount] => 1000 [Ds_Currency] => 978 [Ds_Order] => 180608104552 ........
```

How do I set the Ds_Amount key and value to a variable to use later?

thanks
Craig.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you read the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) about arrays?

Comment: `$VariableToUseLater = $array["Ds_Amount"];`

Comment: It's not clear, why not just `$var = $arr['Ds_Amount'];` ?

Comment: _"to use later"_ - You don't need to put it in a new variable to be able to use it later. You could just use the array.

Comment: thanks all.. yes I've been reading for ages but when I try to echo the value $array['DS_Amount']; it's blank.. I cant seem to echo any of the values to screen

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create your array this way:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    "Ds_Date" => "08%2F06%2F2018",
    "Ds_Hour" => " 12%3A46",
    "Ds_SecurePayment" => "1",
    ...
);

?>
```

And then acces it like this:

```
$array["Ds_Date"]
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks setting it to a variable rather than echoing seems to work ok.. strange.. anyway, next issue is how to a clean up the value.. it's from a urlencoded value so has all the % characters.. can I remove these easily?

Comment: I'm not sure ir I am understanding what do you need... But you can Clean the variable or the array asigning """ to It.  Like $someVariable = "".  Is that what are you asking for??